# If $A\subset B\subset C$, $A$ is dense in $B$, and $B$ is dense in $C$ prove that $A$ is dense in $C$.

Tags: general-topology

> If $A\subset B\subset C$, $A$ is dense in $B$, and $B$ is dense in $C$ prove that $A$ is dense in $C$.

Here's my answer:

$A$ is dense in $B$: $\bar{A}=B$

B is dense in $C$: $\bar{B}=C$

However $\bar{B}$ is the smallest closed set containing $B$.  Therefore $\bar{A}=\bar{B}$ and since $\bar{A}=C$, $A$ is dense in $C$.

My instructor gave me a 2/5, what did I did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it is kind of bad form to answer with $X,Y,Z$ if the question was phrased in terms of $A,B,C$. But I wouldn't take you 60% off because of that.

Regarding the question, note that when you say $\overline X=Y$, you are implying that $Y$ is closed, which is not necessarily the case.

To give an intuitive example, you could have $X=\mathbb Q$, $Y=\mathbb R\setminus\{\sqrt2\}$, $Z=\mathbb R$.

You could use your reasoning if you think in terms of relative topologies. But in that case you must indicate so when you answer the question.

Comment: @user98727: The OP can’t easily use relative topologies here, since there are two that must be kept track of. Yes, one can say that $\operatorname{cl}_YX=Y$ and $\operatorname{cl}_ZY=Z$, and of course it’s then true that $\operatorname{cl}_YX=\operatorname{cl}_YY$, but one cannot then immediately conclude that $\operatorname{cl}_ZX=Z$: one has first to prove that $\operatorname{cl}_ZX=\operatorname{cl}_YX$. It’s true, but assuming it pretty much makes the argument circular. There’s more wrong with the OP’s argument than you’re suggesting.

Answer (score 5):

Presumably $A,B$, and $C$ are all subsets of some topological space $X$. The statement that $A$ is dense in $B$ does not imply that $\operatorname{cl}A=B$: it says only that $\operatorname{cl}A\supseteq B$. (After all, $B$ need not be closed.) Similarly, the statement that $B$ is dense in $C$ tells you only that $\operatorname{cl}B\supseteq C$. Then you can argue that $\operatorname{cl}A$ is a closed set containing $B$, so $\operatorname{cl}A\supseteq\operatorname{cl}B\supseteq C$, and therefore $A$ is dense in $C$.

In other words, your basic approach can be made to work, but you made a pretty significant mistake when you said that $\operatorname{cl}A=B$. (I’m sticking with the original letters; there was no good reason to change them.) I might have made it $3/5$, but I can’t say that $2/5$ is horribly unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

***HINT***: Just because $\bar Y$ is the smallest closed set containing $Y$ does not imply $\bar Y = Y$ (from $\bar X = Y$); take for example $Y = \mathbb{Q}$.